# Average Function performance?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Below is a query that calculates the average vote point of a specific user and puts it in a user table.

```
update usersinfo as users 
       set users.averageVote = 
       (select AVG(vote.votePoint) from votelist as vote 
               where users.userNum = vote.targetUserNum);
```

The 'usersinfo' table has 10K rows, and 'votelist' table has about 15K rows. Each user has 1~3 records of votes.

'votePoint' in 'votelist' table is a tinyint value(0~100).

'userNum' and 'targetUserNum' is a medium int primary key.

'averageVote' in 'usersinfo' table is a decimal(5,2).

The execution time for above query is about 83 seconds. Is there any way to optimize the performance of this query?

Comment: @MitchWheat Do you mean add votePoint as an index? I did that and the execution time went down to 68 seconds. Can there be any other way to reduce time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Create Index 
    I_TargetUserNum 
On votelist(
    targetusernum,
    votepoint
);
```

Comment: reduced to 0.125 seconds... Thanks!!